# Should I ever prefer operators overloading over functions/methods?

Tags: swift, algorithm, operator-overloading

I feel like using operators overloading adds unnecessary complexity and ambiguity to the code.

Does it have its benefits in real-world cases where it's worth to use custom operators or overload existing operators instead of using functions or object methods?

Is it used on a regular basis or more just a funny exotic stuff to add a language a bit more hipness?

Comment: +1 because I feel the same way but never said it out loud. Funnily enough I have been in the field for  over a year now but I have never felt the need to use op-overloading. Looking forward to see what do the more seasoned minds have to say

Comment: @NSNoob in most cases you're right  but when you start doing math stuff (or things related to it) then suddenly things change a lot see my answer

Comment: why close as opinion based? the question seems straight forward to me: `Are overloading meaningful or not?` or am I missing something?

Comment: @Spectre overloaded operators are functions with funny names. The question boils down to whether funny names are useful. Obviously this depends on who does the naming. Primary users of names are people, not tools. Different people like different naming conventions. Ask a diehard COBOL afficionado (if you can find one) and a mathematician whether `+` is a good symbol for integer addition.

Comment: @n.m. interesting point of view ... Didn't look at this in that way as I am dealing mainly with low level code and C++ and there it is usually straightforward with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The main reason for overloading is comfort of using custom `class` with mathematic or logic background**

like:

- vectors
- matrices
- complex numbers
- phasors,tensors,quaternions,...
- finite fields
- big-numbers (arbnum,biginteger,bigdecimal...)
- custom precision floating and fixed formats
- predicates,boolean,fuzy and probabilistic
- strings,lists,ques
- and much much more

If coded right you can write math equations directly and not bother to convert to set of function calls. The reading and understanding math code is much simpler and straightforward with operators.

Sometimes even non strictly math classes are used this way for example images or signals. In **DIP/CV** there are usually math/physics equations applied on those and overloaded operators make that more simple.

**For the non-math classes**

are operators usually useless/meaningless (as you feel) except for special `operator=` which is crucial for any `class/struct` with dynamic allocation members. Without it things like `std:vector<>` will not work properly.

Another example are comparison operators which are sometimes implemented for non math classes to make sorting easier.

Comment: Spektre, thanks for the detailed distinguishing between math and non-math classes!

Answer (score 0):

from wiki
***operator overloading***—less commonly known as operator ad hoc polymorphism—is a specific case of polymorphism, where different operators have different implementations depending on their arguments

Swift has over 40 operators, all of them are overloaded and we are using them on regular bases. Do you  prefer  let sum = value.plus(anotherValue) over let sum = value + anotherValue ?? I am sure, you don't! If the value is custom type conforming to protocol Equatable, == operator must be overloaded and we do it regularly.

Is it a good idea to use custom defined operators (like ±, <*> etc ...)? In that area I am not sure. I am not big fan of this ...

Is it a good idea to overload + operator for something else than sum ? No, definitely not!